# Como posso fazer permissão de localização do aplicativo de forma simples?

Tags: java, android, android-permission

Eu achei esse tutorial https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en 
mas eu não entendi nada.

Olhei esse tutorial:

```
// Here, thisActivity is the current activity
   if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
                Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    // Should we show an explanation?
    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {

        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.

    } else {

        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);

        // MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS is an
        // app-defined int constant. The callback method gets the
        // result of the request.
    }
}
Handle the permissions request response

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
    String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
  switch (requestCode) {
    case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS: {
        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // permission was granted, yay! Do the
            // contacts-related task you need to do.

        } else {

            // permission denied, boo! Disable the
            // functionality that depends on this permission.
        }
        return;
    }

    // other 'case' lines to check for other
    // permissions this app might request
}
```

}

Não entendi para que serve a variável MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS.

Como vocês fazem permissão de localização do aplicativo?

Comment: Aline, eu criei uma lib que facilita muito pra mim. Sempre nos meu projetos eu uso. Funciona da seguinte maneira, declarando a classe PermissManager , eu só chamo o método correspondente ao tipo de permissão. Se tiver interesse, posso entrar com em mais detalhes.

Comment: Tenho interesse

Answer (score 1):

> Não entendi para que serve a variável MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS.

O pedido de permissão é feito com uma chamada ao método [ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.html#requestPermissions(android.app.Activity,%20java.lang.String[],%20int)). A resposta é depois recebida no método [onRequestPermissionsResult()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])).

Uma aplicação pode pedir mais de uma permissão e esses pedidos podem ser feitos em ocasiões diferentes.
Como todas as respostas são recebidas no método `onRequestPermissionsResult()` é necessário ter uma forma de saber a qual pedido ela se refere.

O método `requestPermissions(Activity activity, String[] permissions, int requestCode)`  recebe, no terceiro parâmetro, um inteiro cujo propósito é identificar o pedido(*requestCode*).
Quando a resposta é recebida, ele pode se obtido no primeiro parâmetro do método `onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults)`, possibilitando saber a que pedido se refere a resposta.

O campo `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS` é o valor que identifica o pedido.  Se verificar o código, na parte não postada, verá que ele foi declarado como `int` e tem um valor atribuído. O valor em si não interessa, apenas que seja diferente de qualquer outro usado para pedir permissões.

> Como vocês fazem permissão de localização do aplicativo?

O código mais simples é esse que você postou, no entanto ele refere-se a um pedido de permissão do tipo `Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS`.

Para pedir permissão para saber a localização do aplicativo terá de alterar onde está `Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS` para `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` ou `Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`.

Deverá também alterar o nome da constante `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS` ou criar outra com um nome apropriado, por exemplo `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION`.

Answer (score 0):

A partir do [**Android Marshmallow**](https://www.android.com/intl/pt-BR_br/versions/marshmallow-6-0/), API 23, os usuários concedem permissões a aplicativos enquanto eles estão em execução, não quando eles são instalados.

> Essa abordagem otimiza o processo de instalação de aplicativos, pois o
>   usuário não precisa conceder permissões ao instalar ou atualizar o
>   aplicativo.

Além desta questão, também estabelece ao usuário mais controle sobre os recursos do aplicativo. Por exemplo, um usuário poderia optar por permitir que um aplicativo de câmera tenha acesso à câmera, mas não à localização do dispositivo. O usuário pode revogar as permissões a qualquer momento na tela de configurações da aplicação.

Como é mostrado no momento em que concede a permissão:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Como posso fazer permissão de localização do aplicativo de forma
>   simples?

A princípio eu tive essas mesma certa dificuldades que você está tendo, e pra não enfrenta-la novamente eu criei uma *lib*, justamente para conceder estas permissões de forma mais simples possível.

O *lib* encontra-se no GitHub com o nome [**Permiss**](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/permiss), caso você queria usa, modificar, testar, etc.;

Veja abaixo exemplo, neste caso concedendo permissão de localização.

```
/**
 * This method request permission for get location
 * 
 * @return false/true
 */
public boolean requestPermissLocation() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION },
                ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        Log.i(TAG, "PERMISSION ACCESS LOCATION");

        return false;
    } else
        return true;
}
```

As classes `ContextCompat` e `ActivityCompat` nos permitem manter o código funcionando para versões anteriores ao Android 6.0.

O método `checkSelfPermission()` recebe como parâmetro o contexto atual (em nosso caso a `Activity`) e a permissão que devemos verificar para as funcionalidades seguintes serem utilizadas sem problemas caso concedida. Caso o valor retornado seja diferentes de `PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` devemos seguir na condicional.

O método `requestPermissions()` é o responsável por mostrar a `Dialog` nativa de permissão, apresentada logo acima desta resposta. Em casos onde o `CheckBox` "*Never ask again*" tenha sido selecionado anteriormente ou a permissão já tenha sido concedida a chamada ao `Dialog` é ignorada e nada é apresentado. Note que o segundo parâmetro é um array de String que contém todas as permissões necessárias para a execução da funcionalidade que o usuário solicitou na APP.

> Não entendi para que serve a variável
>   MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS.

O `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS`, neste seu caso seria o terceiro parâmetro do método `requestPermissions()`, que é um inteiro de `8 bits` que será utilizado no método `onRequestPermissionsResult()` para verificar se a permissão foi concedida ou não, caso sim, nesse mesmo mesmo método pode-se chamar a funcionalidade requisitada pelo usuário.

Para utilização da [lib *Permiss*](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/permiss) você vai declarar a classe desta forma:

```
PermissManager permiss = new PermissManager(this);
```

Ai para verificação, você usa a seguinte condição:

```
if (permiss.requestPermissLocation()) {
    // Aqui você insere a instrução desejada 
}
```

Na *lib* também consta os seguintes métodos:

- `requestPermissForRecord()`
- `requestPermissLocation()`
- `requestPermissExtStorage()`
- `requestPermissCamera()`
- `requestPermissContacts()`
- `requestPermissPhone()`
- `requestPermissCalendar()`
- `requestPermissSensors()`
- `requestPermissSMS()`

Pode conferir mais detalhes sobre permissão [na documentação](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/index.html).

Comment: @aline conseguiu resolver seu problema?